# Trouble with adding repository to GitHub via Gitbash/command line

Tags: github, command-line, repository, git-bash

When I try to push a project folder to `GitHub` via command line, I get the error message "

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):

.git" after I paste the link to the repository and type "`git push -u origin master`." What's going on here?

Comment: _Is_ your local directory a Git repository? Git is distributed. You need to have a local repository before you can push anywhere. It sounds like you might need to go through an introductory tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to do create fresh one and delete existing one then follow below steps:

Open git bash command prompt 

--remove the history from
rm -rf .git

--recreate the repo
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"

--push to the github repo
git remote add origin git@github.com<you git loc>
git push -u --force origin master
```

Comment: Please include warnings when recommending things like `rm -rf .git`and `git push --force`. These are dangerous commands and the OP needs to understand what they do instead of blindly copying and pasting them. In any case, it doesn't look like there _is_ a `.git/` directory to remove. The error message indicates that no Git repository exists locally.